# Alternative for Postmessage and sendmessage

Tags: delphi

i have a program which is using several threads to execute some task. Each thread is having a bunch of task to execute. after executing one of them, each thred will call a post message to main screen to update logs.

Now i have sixty thousand tasks ten thousand for each thread - six threads- after executing each task thread is calling post messages. but because of these post messages my application becomes very busy and looks like it hanged.

if i remove post messages...every thing works fine. But i cannot call the procedure directly because it uses ui controls and ui controls are not thread safe and calling procedure directly from thread will lead to other errors.

so is there any alternative available for postmessage and send message.

Thanks,
bASIL

Comment: As a general comment, there is no point updating the GUI faster than the user can "view" the updates. In the case of a grid I have found that if the GUI is updated more than once per second the user cannot "read" the updates. In the case of a label with a count it might be 10 times per second before the user cannot "read" the updates. Remember that the GUI updates are for a human being to see visually, not a machine.

Comment: It might help if you could decribe what the UI update code actually does. The context could help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that there are two message queues for posted messages. The result of this is that *your* posted messages are [always processed before any `Paint`, `Input`, or `Timer` messages.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This means that you are flooding the message queue with a few hundred thousand messages. These messages will always get processed before paint and user messages - making your application appear to hang.

The common way to solve this is to use a timer; have your code start a very short duration (e.g. 0 ms) timer.

> **Clarification**
>
> Timer messages (`WM_TIMER`), like Paint messages (`WM_PAINT`) and Input messages (e.g. WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_KEYDOWN) are processed *after* posted messages. Timer messages specifically are processed after input and paint messages.
>
> This means that your application will respond to user events and paint requests *before* it handles the next `WM_TIMER` message. You can harness this behavior by using a Timer (and it's `WM_TIMER` message), rather than posting a message yourself (which would always take priority over paint and input messages).

When timers fire they send a `WM_TIMER` message. This message will always be handled *after* any input and paint messages; making your application appear responsive.

The other upside of setting a timer is that it forces you to "queue up" all the items you have processed in a (thread safe) list. You combine a few thousand work items into one "timer", saving the system from having to generate and process thousands of needless messages.

### Bonus Chatter

> ...messages are processed in the following order:
>
> - Sent messages
> - Posted messages
> - Input (hardware) messages and system internal events
> - Sent messages (again)
> - [WM_PAINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages
> - [WM_TIMER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) messages

**Update**: You should **not** have a timer polling, that's just wasteful and wrong. Your threads should "*set a flag*" (i.e. the timer). This allows your main thread to actually go idle, only waking when there is something to do.

**Update Two**:

Pseudo-code that demonstrates that order of message generation is not preserved:

```
//Code is public domain. No attribution required.
const
  WM_ProcessNextItem = WM_APP+3;

procedure WindowProc(var Message: TMessage)
begin
   case Message.Msg of
   WM_Paint: PaintControl(g_dc);
   WM_ProcessNextItem:
      begin
          ProcessNextItem();
          Self.Invalidate; //Invalidate ourselves to trigger a wm_paint

          //Post a message to ourselves so that we process the next 
          //item after any paints and mouse/keyboard/close/quit messages
          //have been handled
          PostMessage(g_dc, WM_ProcessNextItem, 0, 0); 
      end;
   else
      DefWindowProc(g_dc, Message.Msg, Message.wParam, Message.lParam);
   end;
end;
```

Even though i generate a `WM_ProcessNextItem` *after* i generate a `WM_PAINT` message (i.e. `Invalidate`), the `WM_PAINT` will never get processed, because there is *always* another posted message before it. And [as MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), paint messages will only appear if there are no other posted messages.

**Update Three**: Yes there is only message queue, but here's why we don't care:

> ### Sent and posted messages
>
> The terminology I will use here is nonstandard, but I'm using it because I think it's a little clearer than the standard terminology. For the purpose of this discussion, I'm going to say that the messages associated with a thread fall into three buckets rather than the more standard two:
>
> ```
> What I'll call them            Standard terminology
> ===========================    =============================
> Incoming sent messages         Non-queued messages
> Posted messages            \_  
> Input messages             /   Queued messages
> ```
>
> In reality, the message breakdown is more complicated than this, but we'll stick to the above model for now, because it's "true enough."

**The Old New Thing, Practical Development Throughout the Evolution of Windows**
by Raymond Chen
ISBN 0-321-44030-7
Copyright © 2007 Pearson Education, Inc.
Chapter 15 - How Window Messages Are Delivered and Retrieved, Page 358

It's easier to imagine there are *two* message queues. No messages in the "second" one will be read until the "first" queue is empty; and the OP is never letting the first queue drain. As a result none of the "paint" and "input" messages in the second queue are getting processed, making the application appear to hang.

> This is a simplification of what actually goes on, but it's close enough for the purposes of this discussion.

**Update Four**

The problem isn't necessarily that you are "flooding" the input queue with your messages. Your application can be unresponsive with only *one* message. As long as you have *one* posted message in the queue, it will be processed before any other message.

Imagine a series of events happen:

- Mouse is moved (`WM_MOUSEMOVE`)
- Mouse left button is pushed down (`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`)
- Mouse left button is released (`WM_LBUTTONUP`)
- The user moves another window out of the way, causing your app to need to repaint (`WM_PAINT`)
- Your thread has an item ready, and Posts a notification (`WM_ProcessNextItem`)

Your application's [main message loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which calls `GetMessage`) will not receive messages in the order in which they happened. It will retrieve the `WM_ProcessNextItem` message. This removes the message from the queue, leaving:

- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`
- `WM_LBUTTONUP`
- `WM_PAINT`

While you process your item the user moves the mouse some more, and clicks randomly:

- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`
- `WM_LBUTTONUP`
- `WM_PAINT`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`
- `WM_LBUTTONUP`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`
- `WM_LBUTTONUP`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`
- `WM_LBUTTONUP`

In response to your `WM_ProcessNextItem` you post another message back to yourself. You do this because you want to process the outstanding messages first, before continuing to process more items. This will add another posted message to the queue:

- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`
- `WM_LBUTTONUP`
- `WM_PAINT`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`
- `WM_LBUTTONUP`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`
- `WM_LBUTTONUP`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`
- `WM_LBUTTONUP`
- `WM_ProcessNextItem`

The problem starts to become apparent. The next call to `GetMessage` will retrieve `WM_ProcessNextItem`, leaving the application with a backlog of paint and input messages:

- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`
- `WM_LBUTTONUP`
- `WM_PAINT`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`
- `WM_LBUTTONUP`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`
- `WM_LBUTTONUP`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_MOUSEMOVE`
- `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`
- `WM_LBUTTONUP`

The solution is to take advantage of the out-of-order processing of messages. Posted messages are always processed before Paint/Input/Timer messages: don't use a posted message. You can *think* of the message queue as being divided into two groups: Posted messages and Input messages. Rather than causing the situation where the "Posted" messages queue is never allowed to empty:

```
Posted messages      Input messages
==================   =====================
WM_ProcessNextItem   WM_MOUSEMOVE
                     WM_LBUTTONDOWN
                     WM_LBUTTONUP
                     WM_PAINT
```

You an use a `WM_TIMER` message:

```
Posted messages      Input messages
==================   =====================
                     WM_MOUSEMOVE
                     WM_LBUTTONDOWN
                     WM_LBUTTONUP
                     WM_PAINT
                     WM_TIMER
```

> **Nitpickers Corner**: This description of two queues isn't strictly true, but it's true enough. How Windows delivers messages in the documented order is an internal implementation detail, subject to change at any time.

It's important to note that you're not *polling* with a timer, that would be bad™. Instead you're *firing* a one-shot timer as a mechanism to generate a `WM_TIMER` message. You're doing this because you know that **timer** messages will not take priority over **paint** or **input** messages.

Using a timer has another usability advantage. Between `WM_PAINT`, `WM_TIMER`, and *input* messages, there is out-of-order processing to them as well:

- *input* messages, then
- `WM_PAINT`, then
- `WM_TIMER`

If you use a timer to notify your main thread, you can also be guaranteed that you will process paint and user input sooner. This ensures that your application remains responsive. It's a usability enhancement and you get it for free.

Comment: A timer polling, which does nothing if no work is required, requires so little CPU time that you would not even be able to measure it. Worrying about this in the scheme of things is rather pointless.

Comment: @Ian, see my post. Having a timer event draining a queue of messages is really an effective way of solving these tasks.

Comment: Actually there's only one queue. The low priority messages get synthesised when the queue is empty.

Comment: For what it's worth, the order of message queue processing does not explain a hang. The only thing that could explain a hang is saturation. Messages being added to the queue at a faster rate than them being removed from the queue.

Comment: @Misha: Polling prevents the thread from going idle, prevents a cpu from going idle, prevents the cpu from entering a low-power state, drains the battery, prevents pages from being swapped out (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/01/24/516808.aspx) It's a bad design that isn't needed in an event-driven operating system.

Comment: @Ian, Windows Explorer polls, so does I suspect just about every application you run (anything with even a single timer). I think most of the arguments in the link you gave a pretty spurious and pretty much irrelevant in modern operating systems. Given the choice between purity and pragmatism, pragmatism wins almost every time, for all commercial software. Why tie yourself in knots trying to be pure when there are usually much bigger problems to solve.

Comment: @Misha: Why? It's the right thing to do. That link is a blog from a Microsoft guy, *on* the team that owns the shell. Goes back to the old question: How do you get developers to pay their taxes? (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/08/22/454487.aspx). How do you get developers to do the right thing? It's something you do, not because it actually benefits you specifically, but because it benefits the software landscape as a whole.

Comment: @Ian, setting the polling timer on/off when appropiate is a good idea. And it would not contradict the event driven scheme.

Comment: Are you going to correct the factual errors? There are not two queues.

Comment: @Ian, we are going to have to agree to disagree. While you may want to benefit the software landscape as a whole, I (like a lot of the comments on your links) are more interested in getting software out the door that is good enough, not perfect, and if good enough is quicker than perfect, I will take that every time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You are correct, which is why i didn't disagree with you. i was interested less in the internal implementation details, as the *concept*, to help the OP understand *why* his application is appearing to hang.

Comment: @Misha The reason i harp on it here is because it's a trivial change. Sometimes generating events is much more difficult than just polling. For example, a web-server waiting for a PDF to be generated (any open handles on it to be closed) so our web-server can send it to the user. Some inter-process communication uses a flag file. Waiting on this file with `FindFirstChangeNotification` is not trivial. But changing `PostMessage` with `SetTimer` *is* trivial. i really wish Task Manager could start pointing out such wasteful programs. But i agree: we disagree.

Comment: Your answer is extremely long but nowhere does it explain why the app is not responsive. It doesn't matter what order events are processed if they can be processed at a rate faster then they are generated. You don't say this. In other regards your answer is excellent but it really ought to address the matter at hand.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The order *does* matter. Imagine i move my mouse, *then* the software calls `PostMessage`. The event that causes a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` happens *before* the event that causes a `WM_ProcessNextItem`. But when the application calls `PeekMessage` they will receive `WM_ProcessNextItem` *first*. The next time the application calls `PeekMessage` it *should* process the `WM_MOUSEMOVE`. Before i do, i call `PostMessage` again. Next time i call `PeekMessage` i *still* won't get the `WM_MOUSEMOVE`. We keep repeating this, and posted messages keep getting processed first - out of order.

Comment: If the system can service the message queue at a faster rate than the rate at which they are added, then the system will not become unresponsive.

Comment: @David Heffernan. Except he can change from processing a custom message to a timer message, and the system will become responsive. He can cause the same number of `WM_TIMER` messages as there were custom messages, and the system will respond. Granted, he should cut down the number of messages: he can cut it down to one. One message could have the system be unresponsive, or it could be responsive, depending on the type of message, because some messages are processed before others.

Comment: @Ian My point (which I can't seem to get across to you) concerns the reason for the non-responsiveness of the original program. "Except he can change from processing a custom message to a timer message, and the system will become responsive." may well be true but that's not the point I am making. You have vast swathes of text, some of which may be relevant, but you do not anywhere explain the problem. Or if you do I can no longer find it because it's lost in huge long lists of unfocused detail.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i don't know what else to say. i know in my head why the program is unresponsive, and it's not because of a volume of messages. It's clear in my own mind. i've tried to explain what i know through the use of metaphor, documentation and examples. i don't know how to get the simple concept out into the answer.

Comment: @ian well it has to be due to volume of messages

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's certainly *better* to have fewer messages. But the problem can be *eliminated* even with the same volume of messages. The problem can also be *reproduced* when there is only one message at a time.

Comment: @Ian All that may well be true but all I was trying to say is that the original problem was down to volume of messages.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The OP needs to be aware that reducing the volume of messages to one at a time will still cause the application to be unresponsive. And, paradoxically, keeping the volume of messages, but using a *different* message, will make the application responsive.

Comment: If the system can service the message queue at a faster rate than the rate at which they are added, then the system will not become unresponsive.

Comment: Paradoxically, keeping the volume of messages, but using a *different* message, will make the application responsive.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ian is specifically referring to the situation where the rate adding messages exactly equals the rate of servicing them (because a new one isn't added until the old one is serviced). In this situation using a timer ensures input messages are processed between the timer messages - and the application remains responsive. Posting the custom message directly ensures the input messages never get processed - and the application is unresponsive. In both cases (to a first approximation anyway) the rate of messages is identical. You're just turning off the queue-jumping.

Answer (score 5):

You are going to struggle to find anything better than PostMessage. My guess is that your problem is that you are updating UI too frequently and your queue is becoming saturated because you cannot service it quickly enough. How about skipping updates if you updated less than a second ago say? If that restores responsiveness then you can consider a more robust solution.

Comment: The problem is user wants to see how many of his task got processed and how much is remaining. so some how we need to update on ui,

Comment: I think David is suggesting something like posting a message with a process to date count and setting a variable equal to now.  Then, when you come in to the process, exit immediately if that variable represents the time less than a second ago.

Comment: @David Heffernan. If the monitor is running at 100Hz, then why not update 100 times a second? My monitor is set for 60Hz, there's no reason a UI can't updated 60 times a second. i hear computers are pretty fast these days. i'm in an application right now that is updating about 132.2 times a second; anything less than 40 times a second is noticeably slow.

Comment: @Ian: Because the human eye can't detect 100 times per second updates? And all of the updates affect performance, since they cause at least a partial redraw. Why overload the message queue with things the eye can't comprehend and that cause other processes to slow down? If you're so bored you need to try and comprehend 100 GUI updates per second, you need either a new job or more work at your current one. :)

Comment: @ian Updating at 100Hz would be fine so long as updates took less than 0.01s to perform. On the other hand the UI thread does not want to consume resources that the worker threads could make better use of.

Comment: @David Heffernan: i absolutely agree; the repainting should only happen if the thread has nothing else to do.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of posting messages, you can put messages in a thread safe queue.

In your main thread, use a timer event to drain the queue.

To remain responsive though, do not stay in the timer event too long.

In many cases I have found this better than posting messages.

In Delphi XE there is a class called TThreadedQueue which you can use.

**Edit :**

I uploaded a sample sort application utilizing different thread to GUI techniques.

See [ThreadedQueueDemo](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=61666&tstart=0)

Comment: But is timer is more faster than post messages, if i make its interwal as 1

Comment: @iambasiljoy, if you enter the timer event 10 times per second, and stay draining the queue for max 50 ms you will have a good responsiveness.

Comment: and consumed half a processor thus denying it for the real work

Comment: @David, without knowing more about the rate the messages are coming and to what purpose, we can only guess. I just meant it is important not to stay in the timer loop too long.

Comment: @Downvoterstepintothelight: It will work, but it will not do what you expect. The rate will be about 40 ms IIRC.

Comment: Thank you very much for the details, BOth timer and Threads are working fine for me, thread seems faster but less responsive. The problem with timer was, it cannot process all the messages posted by six threads. But what i did is inside timer, wrote one while loop also to clear all the queue,so it worked. Also before and after taking the queue i enter in to a critical section to access the queue. other wise some times i was getting access violation.  I choose timer for me, because it is providing good response to UI Controls. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @iambasiljoy, you might consider accepting this as an answer. If you don't have Delphi-XE or XE2 where TThreadedQueue is included, here is link to a thread safe queue : [freepascal-Delphi-thread-safe-queue](http://www.pascalgamedevelopment.com/showthread.php?4961-freepascal-Delphi-thread-safe-queue).

Answer (score 1):

I have done this many times. Have the posted message from the threads update a "cache" on the main form. Have a timer on the main form (set to around 100 ms, or less if you need to) update the main form from the cache. This way the amount of work done per posted message is very small, so the application will spend less time processing and your application will appear "responsive".

Comment: Thank you very much for the details, BOth timer and Threads are working fine for me, thread seems faster but less responsive. The problem with timer was, it cannot process all the messages posted by six threads. But what i did is inside timer, wrote one while loop also to clear all the queue,so it worked. Also before and after taking the queue i enter in to a critical section to access the queue. other wise some times i was getting access violation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new thread for updating logs and in the log threads call TLogThread.Synchronize to update the UI controls that are in the main app thread... or just call TWorkerThread.Synchronize to update the logs from your worker threads.

Comment: i am not so familiar with threads, would you please explain how to implement this.

Comment: Synchroniz won't help. That's equivalent to using SendMessage instead of PostMessage. All your workers will block on the UI updates.